# How to Cancel an Order and Restore Products into Cart without removing existing products in Cart

Tags: php, magento

I have a situation like this,

I tried to place an order, gone to Payment Gateway i left that transaction like that.

In my Magento that order status is Pending Payment, I have created a button in admin panel onclick of the button the following thing will happen.

I want to restore those products into customer Cart with out removing any other products from there cart(if any).

Please have look into my code.

```
      <?php $order_id = 224;
      $_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
      if (!$_order->isCanceled() && !$_order->hasInvoices()) {
          $_order->cancel();
          $_order->addStatusToHistory(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, $message);
          $_order->save();
          $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($_order->getQuoteId());
          $session1 = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
          if ($quote->getId()) {
             $quote->setIsActive(true)->save();
             $session1->setQuoteId($_order->getQuoteId());
          }
          Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setFailureMsg('order_failed');
          Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setFirstTimeChk('0');
      } ?>
```

Because of this code if i have any products in my cart i'm going to loose those products from my cart.

But my concern is without loosing any products from my cart i want to restore these products in Customer Cart.

Any ideas ?

How can i get it done ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as a standalone file or call its methods anywhere you wish to copy an existing customer quote over and set it as active for that customer:

```
require_once( 'app/Mage.php' );

umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

$sCustomerId = 1;
$oCustomer   = Mage::getModel( 'customer/customer' )->load( $sCustomerId );
$sStoreId    = $oCustomer->getData( 'store_id' );
$oQuotes     = Mage::getModel( 'sales/quote' )->getCollection();
$oQuotes->addFieldToFilter( 'customer_id', $sCustomerId );
foreach( $oQuotes as $oQuote )
{
    var_dump( $oQuote->getData( 'is_active' ) );
    $oOrders = Mage::getModel( 'sales/order' )->getCollection();
    $oOrders->addFieldToFilter( 'quote_id', $oQuote->getId() );
    var_dump( $oOrders->count() );

    foreach( $oOrders as $oOrder )
    {
        // If an order is in status...
        if( $oOrder->getData( 'status' ) == 'pending' )
        {
            // Copy the quote over and make it active for your customer.
            $oRevertedQuote = Mage::getModel( 'sales/quote' );
            $oRevertedQuote->merge( $oQuote );
            $oRevertedQuote->setStoreId( $sStoreId );
            $oRevertedQuote->setData( 'is_active', 1 );
            $oRevertedQuote->assignCustomer( $oCustomer );
            $oRevertedQuote->collectTotals()->save();

            // Limit to one conversion at a time?
            break 2;
        }
    }
}
```